# downloading files into Zune

Tags: zune

I got my hand into a old Zune. It does seem functional. I can p[lay songs present in it. But I am just not able to download any files into the player. The songs are my own and I don't want to go through the marketplace. Any suggestions on how to go about to setting up downloading these files into the zune?

Comment: Any errors while downloading the files?

Comment: And also make sure your Zune's firmware is updated to latest version.

Comment: @ahmed I can copy files from the Zune to my computer but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows (XP to 7) you can install the Zune software from www.zune.net.
If you are using a Mac and you have a Zune HD, try http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/apps/mac-connector.aspx.  This may work for older Zune devices.

Once you install the software, you may need to update your device firmware.  Do this - as the software only talks to devices running the latest firmware.

Once this is done you should be able to add any non-DRM music to your "collection" and from then sync to your device.  You can either configure your device to automatically sync, or do manual sync.  in the latter mode, you drag just the artists/albums/songs to the device icon in the lower left.

Answer (score 3):

The [free Zune software](http://www.zune.net/en-us/products/software/download/) is a very nice music library / player.  I've never owned a Zune player but I have enjoyed using the software for years.  It subscribes to and plays video and audio podcasts nicely as well.  My favorite feature is the very handsome "now playing" graphic display in which the software gets images of the artist from the internet and manipulates them into a colorful animated display appropriate to each song as it plays.  Quite cool and great for a party situation!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way should be to use the Zune Software from Microsoft. I've always used that and it's never given me any trouble. Granted, I have a Zune HD, but I'm pretty sure it works with older Zunes.